# Unable to get AngularJS service working in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, service, angular-upgrade

I searched a lot of posts and also the official Angular documentation, but I'm not able to get an AngularJS service running in Angular. I finally came to this page https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule#examples which seems to explain exactly what I need, but when doing all those steps I'm getting:

**ERROR Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.**

My impression is that this example is not quite complete. E.g. there is no hint were the (old) AngularJS framework must be loaded. My service looks like `angular.module('my-module').service('my-service', ...` thus `angular` needs to be defined, otherwise I'm getting an error. Furthermore many examples assume that the AngularJS code is written in TypeScript. In my case this is not true (just plain Javascript).

Unfortunately with Angular 9 there is an additional issue with the `@angular/upgrade` module which is not mentioned anywhere and can only be solved by disabling the new Ivy compiler in `tsconfig.app.json`, otherwise the compiler will throw `Error: Error on worker #1: Error: getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected UpgradeComponent to have an inner class declaration`:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

I'd really appreciate if somebody could post a complete example on what exactly must be done in order to run an AngularJS service in an Angular component.

**UPDATE [6th July 2020]**

Here you can find a GitHub repo which you can clone, to reproduce the behavior: https://github.com/berkon/angularjs-service-upgrade-test. I should also mention that I'm using the Electron framework and started based on this repo https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron but I guess that shouldn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it working! It was really really cumbersome to figure this all out. A lot of things aren't mentioned in most tutorials and even in the official Angular guide there are only code snippets which make it hard for Angular newbies to guess where to put all that stuff. Also the bootstraping is not explained correctly. Furthermore all tutorials assume that the "old" AngularJS code is already written in TypeScript, which makes it even harder to find the right way/order to load/bootstrap/import all that stuff. Finally there seems to be an issue with the @angular/upgrade module in combination with the new Ivy compiler in Angular 9. It throws the error mentioned below. Thus it must be disabled to get things working. A real pain!!!

So roughly these are the steps:

- install the `angular` and `@angular/upgrade` node modules
- load all `.js` modules including AngularJS in the `script` section of `angular.json`
- interrupt the regular Angular bootstrap process by removing the `bootstrap` section from @NgModule and bootstrap AngularJS via `ngDoBootstrap` manually. First bootstrap
  AngularJS, afterwards bootstrap the AppComponent class. This way the service is available at AppComponent initialization. Otherwise you'll get an injection error!
- Add a new provider in `providers []` section to get access to the new service
- Now the new (upgraded) service can be injected in the constructor of AppComponent

Its quite a lot of work to perform all steps below manually, but I listed them for reference. Here you can find a GitHub repo where you can clone a working app. Don't be surprised! This repo uses the Electron framework (electronjs.org). But don't worry this doesn't have any influence on my findings: https://github.com/berkon/angularjs-service-upgrade-test

And here is the step-by-step guide:

**Prerequistes**

- execute `npm install angular --save`
- execute `npm install @angular/upgrade --save`
- in `tsconfig.app.json` add `"enableIvy": false` to `angularCompilerOptions` to avoid getting:

  ```
  Error: getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected UpgradeComponent to have an inner class declaration
  ```
- add `"node_modules/angular/angular.js"` and the Javascript file which contains your AngularJS service (in this case `"src/app/angular-js-service.js"`) to the `scripts []` array in `angular.json`

**app.module.ts**

- add `ApplicationRef` to the import brackets of `@angular/core`
- add `import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static'`
- add `UpgradeModule` to `imports []` array of `@NgModule`
- remove `bootstrap` section completely from `@NgModule` and replace it with this: `entryComponents: [AppComponent]`
- add this to the `providers []` array in `@NgModule` and make sure to replace `myService` with the correct name of your service:

  ```
  { provide: 'myService', useFactory: (i: any) => { return i.get('myService') }, deps: ['$injector'] }
  ```
- replace the constructor of `AppModule` with this:

  ```
  constructor ( public upgradeModule: UpgradeModule ) {}
  ```
- add this to the `AppModule` class and make sure to replace `ajsAppModule` with the name of your AngularJS main app module:

  ```
  ngDoBootstrap ( appRef: ApplicationRef ) {
      this.upgradeModule.bootstrap(document.body, ['ajsAppModule'], { strictDi: true } )
      appRef.bootstrap ( AppComponent )
  }
  ```

**app.component.ts**

- add `Inject` to the import brackets at `@angular/core`
- in the `AppComponent` class change the constructor to this and make sure to replace `myService` with the name of your AngularJS service

  ```
  constructor ( @Inject('myService') myService: any ) {
      myService.doSomething()
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and I solved it in my app, however I cannot remember exactly why this was happening (sorry, it was a long time ago). I wasn't upgrading services, instead I was downgrading.

Here's my app.module.ts I've added comments to the parts that were critical to get this working, I hope there may be a hint for you here. Note that I used the Angular CLI to generate the app.

```
setAngularJSGlobal(angular);

// Configure the angularjs app (yours might be defined elsewhere)
const app = angular.module('app', [MyFormsModule, AngularMaterialModule]);

app.run(RunAddressAutocompleteConfig);
app.run(RunDynamicQueryConfig);

// Downgrade Angular AppComponent so AngularJS can render it after bootstrapping
// my app used an Angular component as the root
app.directive('appRoot', downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }));

// Downgrade Angular services
app.factory('api', downgradeInjectable(ApiService));
app.factory('dynamicQuery', downgradeInjectable(DynamicQueryService));

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FormDirective,
    FormPageComponent,
    FormsListPageComponent,
    RouterLinkPreserveQueryParamsDirective,
    FormEmptyStatePageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, UpgradeModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, CommonModule],
  // This was absolutely necessary for bootstrapping my app in this way
  // I encountered errors otherwise
  providers: [
    {
      provide: '$scope',
      useExisting: '$rootScope',
    },
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private readonly upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [app.name], { strictDi: true });
    appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
  }
}
```

index.html

```html
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'll have a look. In my case I need to upgrade. Meanwhile I found out where/how I can load the AngularJS framework (once I got everything working, I'll post it here), but I still have an issue with the bootstrap order. When I'm doing it like described in most of the tutorials (first bootstraping Angular and then within the platformBrowserDynamic() enclosure bootstraping AngularJS), I'm always getting the injector error mentioned in my description when trying to inject the upgraded service into a component.

Comment: Yeah, some more code would definitely help a lot. Do you think it might be too much trouble to try get a minimal repro on github and link it back?

Comment: Not at all. That's a good idea! I have an example to play with, which I've built from scratch to exclude any other effects. I just need to clean it up a little and then I'll link it here asap.

Comment: I've just updated the description above with a link to a GitHub repo which should show the the issue. I've also added some comments / console.log() in the code to explain what I want to achieve. Would be great if you can help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Just committed a change. I forgot to remove the bootstrap option in NgModule and also forgot to add ngDoBootstrap() in AppModule class. Now the Injector error is gone, but the constructor of AppComponent class is not called anymore when I remove "bootstrap" from NgModule.